# php mail function in background

Tags: php

I have written a function which receives some parameters (email addresses) and send email. I need this to be executed on a user action like follows-

Somebody answers a question, an HTTP request to add the question, a controller receives the request and adds the question to the database. Now I want that I call the function to send email but not wait it to complete - so returning the HTTP response.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a column to the database - a boolean or timestamp - which indicates whether or not an email has been sent. Then set up a cron job to send emails for those records.

This also makes it easier to limit the # of emails being sent at a time.

Comment: Yes. This absolutely makes sense. I think I will do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a separate PHP script and run it as a separate process via `exec`

```
exec('mailer.php &');
```

Comment: You need `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to be 100% sure that it will release immediately, sometimes `&` by itself just doesn't cut it. You need to send `STDOUT` and `STDERR` somewhere else as well.